# JQuery UI tab slow response with 500+ row table

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I am currently running into an issue with JQuery UI tabs causing the browser to slow down a lot when I load a large table into a tab.  I am running JQuery 1.4.2 and JQuery UI 1.8.4.  Clicking anywhere within the tab with this large table causes the CPU to jump up to 50%.  The slowness is more apparent if you have a column of checkboxes to click on.  But it is also apparent when you attempt to highlight any text in the table.

So far I have tested the following:

1) JQuery UI tabs with a 500 row table.

2) JQuery UI tabs with 500 rows of data (replaced table with p and span tags).

3) Just a 500 row table

Case #1 is the slowest.
Case #2 is more responsive, but the table layout is now gone.
Case #3 is the fastest with no lag time at all.

I've tried using the FireBug profiler to see what could be executing, but it returned with no activity.  At this point I am stumped.

Here is a code snippet for Case #1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Tabs + 500 row table</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">500 Rows</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">

<!-- Insert Large data table here.  500+ rows -->

<!--
  Small sample starter table.  Pasting a 500 row table here would be too much.  
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
       <td>column 2</td>
       <td>column 3</td>
       <td>column 4</td>
       <td>column 5</td>
       <td>column 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
-->

</div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this with a sort of "hack".  I simply removed the ui-widget class from the tabs after loading the tabs and I no longer have high cpu usage with huge tables.

```
$("#tabs").removeClass("ui-widget");
```

I was able to safely remove this because this class adds very little to the actual style of the tabs other than setting the font type and size.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be related to the bug mentioned here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6757

in the CSS change

```css
.ui-widget :active {
    outline: none;
}
```

to

```css
.ui-widget:active {
    outline: none;
}
```